# Why does this form get submitted even if the required fields are left empty?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with a form in which i take the password input from the user and then javascript checks if the passwords match. But even if the password is required, the form gets submitted if the input box is left empty. I am using javascript to submit the form. Although i have a solution to my problem but i wanted to ask that why this is happening and not the normal action of `Please fill in this field`, which normally appears when doing so.

HTML-

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST" id="userform">
USERNAME:<input name="uname" type="text" required/>
PASSWORD:<input type="password" id="upass" name="upass" type="text" required/>
RETYPE PASSWORD:<input type="password" id="reupass" name="reupass" type="text" required/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="passCheck()">
</form>
```

JavaScript-

```
function passCheck(){
var pass1 = document.getElementById('upass').value;
var pass2 = document.getElementById('reupass').value;
if(pass1 == pass2){
    document.getElementById('userform').submit();
}
else{
    alert("Both password inputs do not match. Please retry.");
    document.getElementById('userform').reset();
}
}
```

EDIT-
I want that this should appear when i click on the button and the password fields are left empty:https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGuCK.jpg

Comment: Don't put the listener on the submit button, put it on the form's submit handler. A form can be submitted a number of ways without clicking the submit button. Also, you can reference the form as `document.forms.userform`. Lastly, it's not nice to reset the form just because the user made a mistake, let them fix it themselves.

Comment: Also, you will still need to validate the values on the server side. You can't depend on JavaScript validation because it can be turned off or form values sent from outside a browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in order for the forms to not be submitted, your function must return false, as well as check to make sure the passwords aren't blank, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/upgradellc/Heay3/5/

javascript:

```
function passCheck(){
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('upass').value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById('reupass').value;
    if(pass1 == pass2 && pass1 != ""){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert("Both password inputs do not match. Please retry.");
        document.getElementById('userform').reset();
        return false;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST" id="userform" onSubmit="return passCheck()" >
    USERNAME:<input name="uname" type="text" />
    PASSWORD:<input type="password" id="upass" name="upass" type="text" />
    RETYPE PASSWORD:<input type="password" id="reupass" name="reupass" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Please explain. Isn't using using `document.getElementById('userform').submit();` same as clicking on a submit button

Comment: @Sid I have updated my answer. Submit() is indeed the same as clicking on the submit button- but unless your onclick function returns false, the form is still going to submit :-)

Comment: @Max, You need not return false. I tested without the return and it works perfectly

Comment: @RishiDua no, you do need to return false in the case of an onSubmit event

Comment: ... So does mine, using the recommended onSumbit event of a form, which is much simpler than using a button and calling submit()

Comment: Yep, you're right. I was just saying that you do not NEED to return false if you are using a function for onclick(), the way OP was doing it

Comment: sure, but for validation it's generally better to use onSubmit

Answer (score 3):

That is because if both are blank

```
pass1 = NULL pass2 = NULL
```

Which essentially means `pass1 == pass2`

[EDIT]
Change your code to

```
function passCheck(){
var pass1 = document.getElementById('upass').value;
var pass2 = document.getElementById('reupass').value;
if((pass1 == pass2) && (pass1!="")){
    document.getElementById('userform').submit();
}
else{
    alert("Both password inputs do not match. Please retry.");
    document.getElementById('userform').reset();
}
}
```

Comment: but that doesn't happen when you submit the form using html

Comment: Here when we are using JavaScript, two variables are equal even if they are null. I'm sorry I didn't get what do you mean when you say submit the form using html?

Comment: i meant this:`<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: That is because required tag works only for the html submit option. Since you are manually submitting using document.getElementById('userform').submit(), you need to check if the password field is blank or not.

Comment: but i want that tag to appear

Comment: Got you.. In that case, input type=Submit is your way to go!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to submit the form if password does not match then you have to return false

do like this :- `return false`

```
if(pass1!='' && pass2!='')
 {

    if(pass1 == pass2){
            document.getElementById('userform').submit();
        }
        else{
            alert("Both password inputs do not match. Please retry.");
            document.getElementById('userform').reset();
            return false;
        }

}
```

Also

you have to change your `input type="button"` to `input type="submit"`

**EDIT** :-

You also have to check first wheather your password field is empty or not ,if it is empty then show error and return false

Comment: if i change the input type="button" to input type="submit" then i will not be able to validate if password inputs match and the form will be submitted

Comment: @Sid yes, you will be able to- look at my answer.

Comment: <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="passCheck()"> yes you can,  see form will not submit if you do return false when password does not matched and if password matched then it will automatically submit your form since in that you are not doing return false

Answer (score 0):

[Here is working JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cm4pa/). try this code:

```
if(pass1 !="" && pass1 != pass2){
    alert("Both password inputs do not match. Please retry.");
    document.getElementById('userform').reset();
    return false;
}
else{
   document.getElementById('userform').submit();
}
```

#### Edit

if you change input type to `submit` it will automatically check null constraint and still you can validate fields

[Here is Demo with type SUBMIT](http://jsfiddle.net/Cm4pa/3/)

Comment: But if both the password fields are left empty, then also `pass1==pass2` is true and the form will be submitted

Comment: pass1 != "" will handle it

Comment: I think OP is using `type="button"`

Comment: type="submit" button will not submit the form here independent of any condition because you have overwriten the action using onclick="passCheck()"

Comment: default action occurs after passCheck() if you dont return false

Comment: I want to check if the password inputs match and then submit the form. That is why i am using input type="button"

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST" id="userform" onsubmit="return validate()" >
    USERNAME:<input name="uname" id="uname" type="text" required />
    PASSWORD:<input type="password" id="upass" name="upass" type="text" required />
    RETYPE PASSWORD:<input type="password" id="reupass" name="reupass" type="text" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And

```
function validate(){
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('upass').value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById('reupass').value;
    var username= document.getElementById('uname').value;
    if(username == ""){
        alert('user name cannot be empty')
        return false
    }

    if(pass1 == ""){
        alert('password cannot be empty')
        return false
    }

    if(pass1 != pass2){
        alert("Both password inputs do not match. Please retry.");
        return false;
    }

    return true
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KZqQz/3/)

Comment: `type="button"` won't submit the form.

Comment: This works and i also can see the `Please fill in this field` tip if a field is left empty. Thank you

Comment: @Sid, If you didn't want to do anything with the submit button, why did you use onclick="passCheck()"?
I gave you the JavaScript solution assuming passCheck() has some more lines of code (for some other purpose which you have removed here for simplicity)